# How to assign "*" to IfMatch - conditional header

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, azure-blob-storage, etag

I download blob content from Azure blob storage. I am trying to set conditional header ETag value as "*".

When i give IfMatch = "*", says cannot implicitly convert string to Azure.ETag.

```
        Conditions = new BlobRequestConditions()
        {
           IfMatch = "*"  

        }
```

How do I assign IfMatch to *. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but you are looking for this? You can not assign a String value to an ETag

```
IfMatch = new ETag("*")
```